# Social Media share plugin as Popup

Tags: html, share, addthis, sharethis

I am looking for a Social Media sharing plugin which show the share icon as popup when one hover or click on the share icon as show in images below. I looked for similar option and tried `addthis` and `sharethis` but could not find an option. can we modify `addthis` plugin to make it work like as show in image below

[image].

Answer (score 1):

Go check out sharrre.   jQuery and very easy to customize.

http://sharrre.com/

Hope this helps.

Heres my personal favourite style: http://sharrre.com/example2.html